# Grails query using $where with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to query mongo using the $where directive within Grails/GORM?

I'm trying to run a mongo query much like the following:

```
db.myAwesomeCollection.find({
    $where : function() { 
        /* Do Something Really Special */
        return true; // or false
    }
});
```

Comment: There are some [notable concurrency and performance caveats](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations) to using `$where`, so it might be better to ask for suggestions on how to efficiently approach a specific query. There are very few recommendable Really Special use cases for `$where`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. For the sake of the question, however, let's pretend that this is a Really Special use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I've added a mongoOperations bean to the resources.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<mongo:mongo id="myreplicaset" replica-set="${grails.mongo.replicaSet}">
    <mongo:options
            connections-per-host="300"
            threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="5"
            connect-timeout="10000"
            max-wait-time="120000"
            auto-connect-retry="true"
            socket-keep-alive="false"
            socket-timeout="0"
            slave-ok="false"
            write-number="0"
            write-timeout="0"
            write-fsync="false"/>
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory dbname="${grails.mongo.databaseName}" id="mongoDbFactory" mongo-ref="myreplicaset"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION"/>
</bean>

<alias name="mongoTemplate" alias="mongoOperations"/>
```

Then in my controller, I inject the mongoOperations object:

```
def mongoOperations;
```

I can then call the find() operation on the mongoOperations bean directly.

```
String function = "function() { " +
    "return // true if the row matches your criteria" +
    "}";

Query query = new BasicQuery("{\$where : \"" + function + "\"}");
List<MyDomainClass> results = mongoOperations.find(query, MyDomainClass.class);
```